# AngularJS - select with track by doesn't set list object in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-model

I've got a select:

```
<select name="data_source" class="form-control" ng-model="data.data_source" ng-options="c.name for c in data_sources track by c.id"></select>
```

Data_source objects in my data_sources array are of the form

```
{id:"myid", name:"mydatasourcename", ...}
```

On init data.data_source contains an object I retrieve from db

```
{id:"myid"}
```

Correct value is displayed in the select but in my ng-model I have my original data_source object with only the 'id' attribute. What I would have here is the object coming from the data_sources array with all its attributes (name and other).
Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: `ng-model` should be the `$scope` variable where the selected value is stored, not the data array you use in `ng-options`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though on changing the drop-down your ng-model will automatically be updated with all properties.
On init you can update your data_source in below manner

```
data.data_source = dataFromSever
data_sources = dataListFromServer
//now get the matched obj of data_sources array by matching data_source.id
//set data_source = matchedObj.. This will ensure the correct structure of model at init
```